# Magical Letters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to take one letter, say, "A" and turn it into a symbol, but still be able to turn it back to its original form (case-sensitive)?

For example:

```
public void doIt(string input)
{
   // do magic work


   // display result
}

*Input = A
*Result = ^$
```

Comment: What kind of symbol? Like Wingdings?

Comment: put some example dear...

Comment: I'm not sure. Anything that is possible. And WingDings is a Font, I mean like... Unicode or Hex values or something?

Comment: @Lucifer, the rule is that if you're going to talk about magic, you have to spell it right. +1 to anyone who retags this with the `magic` tag.

Comment: You could Base64 the text :-) Or ROT13! ROT13 is surely the best way to encrypt your text :-) :-)

Comment: For completeness it should be added, that any algorithm which is (easily, YMMV) reversible (like translation tables, etc.) is *not* suitable for encryption. Passwords, etc. come to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string ORIGINAL_CHARS = "ABCD";
string MAGICAL_CHARS = "$#@%";

public void DoMagic(string input)
{
    string output = input;
    for (int i = 0; i < ORIGINAL_CHARS.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i > MAGICAL_CHARS.Length)
        {
            continue;
        }
        output = output.Replace(ORIGINAL_CHARS[i], MAGICAL_CHARS[i]);
    }
    return output;
}

public void UndoMagic(string input)
{
    string output = input;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAGICAL_CHARS.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i > ORIGINAL_CHARS.Length)
        {
            continue;
        }
        output = output.Replace(MAGICAL_CHARS[i], ORIGINAL_CHARS[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[See here on how to use XOR (exclusive ors) to encode and decode messages.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Language-Basics/UseXORtoencodeanddecodeamessage.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your not talking about some specific set of symbols, and you just want to "encrypt" your text in such a way, then you should take ASCII code of your letter, process it through some function and you'll have your "encrypted" letter. Then latter, pass it to some decryption function - and you'll get your letter back.

for example

```
public char Encrypt(char val)
{
    var ascii = (int)val;
    return (char)(ascii+44);
}

public char Decrypt(char val)
{
    var ascii = (int)val;
    return (char)(ascii-44);
}
```

If you want to print the "enrypted" characters, then you have to make sure, that your transformation function transforms them into printable character space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the algorithm you use to transform into a "symbol" is reversible, then yes you can turn it back.

For a more precise answer, you'll have to provide a lot more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char ch in input) {
    sb.Append((char)(0x660 + ch));
}
var output = sb.ToString()

// 0x660 should be in the middle of the Arabic block
```

There should be 112 printable characters, starting from 0x660, and you asked for "letters" in the input. Given your example, I consider letters to be `[A-Za-z]`.

If you meant "given some UNICODE "printable" symbols, change them to other UNICODE "printable" symbols", THAT is another problem (quite difficult).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **XOR** operator:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Original
     string input = "ala bala portocala";
     Console.WriteLine(input);

     // XORed
     Console.WriteLine(doIt(input));

     // Double XORed to get original back
     Console.WriteLine(doIt(doIt(input)));

}

public string doIt(string input)
{
    var aChars = input.ToCharArray();
    var aCharsRes = new char[aChars.Length];
    for (int i=0; i<aChars.Length; i++)
    {
        aCharsRes[i] = (char)(aChars[i] ^ 1);
    }

    return new string(aCharsRes);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The *doIt* function can be refactored to take advantage of **LINQ**. Here is the one liner:

```
 public string doItOneLiner(string input)
 {
     return new string(input.ToCharArray().Select(s => (char)(s ^ 1)).ToArray());
 }
```